# java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class [0x25] tried to get class from non-reference register v12 (type=Imprecise Constant: 127)

Tags: android

crash after remove "-dontshrink" in proguard-rules.pro

log:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.xxx.activity.XXActivity:
androidx.loader.content.Loader com.xxx.activity.XXActivity.onCreateLoader(int, android.os.Bundle) failed to verify: 
androidx.loader.content.Loader com.xxx.activity.XXActivity.onCreateLoader(int, android.os.Bundle): 
[0x25] tried to get class from non-reference register v12 (type=Imprecise Constant: 127)
```

if add "-dontshrink" to proguard-rules.pro, there has no crash.